# Altering character limit on Heroku PostGRES doesn't change column in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

In my Heroku postgres db, I had a column of type "string" with a limit of "50" characters.

I just made a migration that changed the limit to 80 characters.

```
class ChangeTagLineLimit < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :blocks, :tag_line, :string, :limit => 80
  end
  def down
    change_column :blocks, :tag_line, :string, :limit => 50
  end
end
```

However when I try to save a record, I get this error:

`PG::StringDataRightTruncation: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(50)`

It sounds like PostGRES hasn't changed the size of the varchar column. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That migration should work. The error is probably related to another table that didn't get migrated yet.